# Is there a web UI for modifying I18n locales for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I'm looking for a way to modify the values of I18n yml files for locales via web gui, is there some gem for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I modified the Newsdesk's translate plugin for using with Rails 3:

https://github.com/romanbsd/translate

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, it seems to do what I need, do you know if its only for development o also for production?

Comment: It's limited to development, since you probably don't want strangers to modify your translations. But you can change https://github.com/romanbsd/translate/blob/master/config/routes.rb if you like.

Comment: It would be nice if authenticated admin users could modify it in development, I'll check it out.

Comment: Yeah, you can use Devise and/or cancan for that. Keep me posted!

Answer (score 10):

A gem that mimics Twitter Translation Center [github.com/badrit/translation_center](http://github.com/badrit/translation_center)

Comment: Many awesome features there!

Comment: I was searching for a relevant Gem, and I found you :) ! Great deed you have here guys, But is their a NoSQL/Mongo compatible version ?

Comment: Translation Center supports only ActiveRecord, they may support Mongo in the future.

Comment: Anyone knows if translator center is open source?

Comment: @Mr.Pichler yes, the gem is open source and here you're the link github.com/badrit/translation_center

Comment: Tried it out but ran into quite a few issues - Assumes a specific configuration and javascript libraries. Couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

Tolk is a web interface for doing i18n translations packaged as an engine for Rails 4 applications

https://github.com/tolk/tolk

Answer (score 3):

There's also tolk written by the creator of rails:

https://github.com/dhh/tolk

Comment: I think that it's only for Rails 2.3, though :(

Comment: I've heard of it from DHH but yes it says it only works for 2.3, bummer.

Comment: The Rails 3 branch doesn't work with non-ActiveRecord ORMs, either (Mongoid, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

In http://rst-it.com we also had problems with finding the right solution, so we decided to make an activeadmin translation panel with interface similar to http://www.localeapp.com/.

Currently we are in design stage (first draft is on https://github.com/KMPgroup/active_I18n) but next week we will have working solution.

I will post here info when we lunch it, but in the meantime you can check https://github.com/KMPgroup/active_I18n and tell us what you think or even write an issue - the more feedback at the beginning the better.

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising too:

http://www.localeapp.com/

I think I will give it a try. Anyone has experience with this service?

Comment: Not free project... so shame. Need the same open souce project^^

Comment: I created an account and uploaded my yml only to be told I'd have to pay to be able to actually use it - their free tier assumes you are starting with a new app. No reply from their support team when I asked to be able to try before I buy.

Comment: 2016 update: Free plan with 2 locales, and 500 translation keys.