# Ruby on Rails: what is the best choice of Web UI for managing I18n yml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, internationalization, translation

I want to grant to external people possibility to change translation in my project. I want to use web interface for it. And I want all this changes to be git commited. And, if it possible, I want to see authors of changes, so in the best case this web ui should have users and it's own authorization system.

I found question [Is there a web UI for modifying I18n locales for Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984626/is-there-a-web-ui-for-modifying-i18n-locales-for-rails-3), but this isn't satisfy all conditions (like git for example or different users).

So it would be great if you pointing such Web UIs to me.

P.S. I use Rails 3

Answer (score 2):

Rails Translation Center Gem is awesome! https://github.com/BadrIT/translation_center
It is free; you don't need to pay for such locale or phrase!

Answer (score 1):

We are using https://webtranslateit.com/ with our Rails 3 project.

It has users, translator groups etc. and works pretty well. It can read the changes of the translation files from git, but it cannot commit automatically back. However, for us that has not been a problem as when there are updated translations some of the developers can easily do a "WTI pull" to get newest translations, check that nothing is broken and make a git commit of those.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the translate app would do what you want, just add git commits to it.  There's a storage module.  Fork the repo, add git functionality using the ruby-git gem.  Make a git commit call after the yml file is written.  You'll have to hook the commit.author.name and commit.author.email to your authorization system in Rails to make it "multi-user".

Should be a fun little project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [locale](https://www.localeapp.com) or [phrase](https://phraseapp.com). They are both free in beta.
Alternatively, you can setup your own translation web service with [copycopter](https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server).